# Fancybox Conflict with ionic 1 jqLite

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fancybox, jqlite, ionic-v1

I am using fanybox 3 in my Angular Js 1.3 web application and it works fine. However, when I use the fancybox inside the ionic 1 app, I am receiving the following error when the photo is swiped:

```
Uncaught TypeError: cssClasses.indexOf is not a function
    at n.fn.init.jqLite.removeClass (ionic-angular.js:268)
```

This error only happens when the photo is swiped in touch screen and not when the next and prev buttons are pressed. Looking at the `ionic-angular.js:268` line, this is what it is:

```
jqLite.prototype.removeClass = function(cssClasses) {
  var x, y, splitClasses, cssClass, el;
  if (cssClasses) {
    for (x = 0; x < this.length; x++) {
      el = this[x];
      if (el.getAttribute) {
        if (cssClasses.indexOf(' ') < 0 && el.classList.remove) {
          el.classList.remove(cssClasses);
        } else {
          splitClasses = cssClasses.split(' ');

          for (y = 0; y < splitClasses.length; y++) {
            cssClass = splitClasses[y];
            el.setAttribute('class', (
                (" " + (el.getAttribute('class') || '') + " ")
                .replace(/[\n\t]/g, " ")
                .replace(" " + cssClass.trim() + " ", " ")).trim()
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return this;
};
```

I dont know why the ionic angular line is triggered when fancybox image is swiped. I am suspecting maybe the jqLite used in ionic 1 is conflicting with the jquery 2.1.4 that was included before that together with my angular app?

Or is there some other reason for this issue? Can you help me here please?

Comment: Well, if you could edit that file and add additional validation for `cssClasses` type (e.g., if it is a string), then it might start working (sorry, I have no idea what ionic 1 jqLite is, how it works or why this question is related to `ionic 1 jqLite`, because fancybox v3 is just a jQuery plugin).

Comment: Thank you @Janis. My app has jquery included but my mobile application encapsulates my application inside ionic and ionic by default uses jqLite bundled with it. Thats why the fancybox inside my web application does not have this issue since it does not use ionic but my mobile app throws the error.

Comment: You are right. Adding a validation check for `cssClasses` inside my `ionic-angular.js` seems to fix it and the fancybox touch slide works fine now. I added this in that file: `if (cssClasses && typeof cssClasses === 'string')`. This is not an ideal solution because the `ionic-angular.js` is the core file that comes with ionic bundle and future updates will overwrite this file. But I have kept a note on this so if the error happens again, I will know what is causing it. Thank you so much @Janis for pointing this out.

Comment: @Janis jqLite is a tiny, API-compatible subset of jQuery that allows AngularJS to manipulate the DOM in a cross-browser compatible way. jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality with the goal of having a very small footprint. See [AngularJS API Reference - jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite)

Comment: Well, you could create a pull request with that fix, most likely it will be included in the source :) The problem is that jQuery`s methods typically accept method as an argument (for example, https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/), therefore jqLite is not 100% compatible with jQuery.

Comment: Also, fancybox starting from v4 will drop jQuery dependency and we will leave these issues behind.

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciate your help.

Comment: If you can add your comment as the answer, since it did help me resolve my issue, I am happy to accept it and close this question. Regards.